# remove special character (^@) with sed

Tags: sed

I want to remove "^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@" from my textfile. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
sed -i 's/\\^@//g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Remove one backslash.

Comment: Those are almost certainly NUL characters and if your file contains those then it's 100% not a text file as that's the one character not allowed in a text file (See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) and so YMMV with trying to use any text-processing tool such as sed on it. Can you fix whatever is producing such files to produce valid text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^@` is one of the ways how to display the null byte. `sed` (at least the GNU one) represents it as `\x00`:

```
sed 's/\x00//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is not generally robust against null characters. But Perl is, and `tr`:

```sh
tr -d '\000' <myfile.txt >newfile.txt
```

Some `sed` variants will be able to handle null bytes with the notation which works in Perl:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/\x00//g' myfile.txt
```

The `-i` option says to replace the original file, like some `sed` variants also allow you to.

Comment: Your presentation is somewhat unclear, but `^@` is usually a representation of the ASCII `NUL` character. (If you wanted to replace a literal caret `^` followed by a literal `@`, your `sed` script would work if you removed the first backslash; the double backslash would match a literal backslash instead of escape the caret, which is otherwise a regex special character which matches start of line).